# Regex Matching Second Column from MMLS command in Bash

Tags: regex

I am writing a script to match a specific value (The start column) from MMLS.

The output is similar to:

```
#     Slot    Start        End          Length       Description
#00:  Meta    0000000000   0000000000   0000000001   Safety Table
#01:  -----   0000000000   0000002047   0000002048   Unallocated
#02:  Meta    0000000001   0000000001   0000000001   GPT Header
#03:  Meta    0000000002   0000000033   0000000032   Partition Table
#04:  00      0000002048   0001026047   0001024000   SYSTEM
#05:  01      0001026048   0001288191   0000262144   Microsoft reserved partition
#06:  02      0001288192   0625141759   0623853568   Windows
#07:  -----   0625141760   0625142447   0000000688   Unallocated
```

Being new to regex, my current Regex looks like:

```
 [^ ]+\s+[^](?=\s.*SYSTEM)
```

Which matches Slot, Start, and End of the SYSTEM line with trailing spaces, if I wanted to only match the Start column what would be the best approach?

Constraints: There will not always be 7 slots and the sizes will vary.

Comment: Which column you want second or first? ANd which lang/tool you're running?

Comment: Because this won't actually need a regex..

Comment: @AvinashRaj I am matching in Bash with the intent to assign the Start value using the description qualifier to a variable for later use. Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: @ImNotLeet: Do you want to do this using Unix tools?

Comment: @anubhava it is in a Unbuntu environment

Comment: ok check my updated answer for awk solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match all `start` columns (#3):

```
/^(?:\S+\s+){2}(\S+)/gm
```

To match only when `SYSTEM` is found on the line:

```
/^(?:\S+\s+){2}(\S+)(?=\s.*SYSTEM)/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uE7dQ0/3)

---

**Update:** If running in Ubuntu you can use a simple awk like this:

```
awk '/SYSTEM/{print $3}' file
0000002048
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it simply using `awk` :

To print any i<sup>th</sup>, you can do it using awk as:

```
awk '{print $i}'
```

If you want to select a specific line containing `PATTERN` and print its i<sup>th</sup> column:

```
awk '/PATTERN/{print $i}'
```

Here in your example:

To print the `start` column completely:

```
awk '{print $3}'
```

Output:

```
Start
0000000000
0000000000
0000000001
0000000002
0000002048
0001026048
0001288192
0625141760
```

To print the `start` column value of the line containing `SYSTEM`:

```
awk '/SYSTEM/{print $3}'
```

Output:

```
0000002048
```